# How can apply bootstrap classes like and their respective behavior to only mobile mode using media queries?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries, css-tables

I have a table in application who use UI breaks when the screen width reduces to lesser than 600px. Now I want to apply the following bootstrap classes that add a scroll to the application :

```
 .table-scrollable .table-scrollable-borderless
```

But, I don't want the scrolls to appears in Desktop UI.

So, I decided to use the media query :

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {

}
</style>
```

But, since these are not my own custom designed class but instead are classes inherited from bootstrap. I dont know how to invoke from the media queries.

And I can't change the class names either because I am sure, there will be some jquery that generate the scrolls based on these class names.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the property

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

To the element you want to have a scroll bar. And `borderless` is of course achievable via `border: none;`.

Please note, when adding `overflow-y: scroll`, it's important that you have a set `height`. Hope this helps.